# Packaging Fresh Fruit in Aluminum Cans but still spoiled after 7 days

Tags: chemical-engineering

I am doing small experiment where I put fresh fruit inside a standard aluminium cans, then use an industrial seamer to close the lid. I also put juiced version of it (with only water and sugar) in another can

After 7 days, opened both and it stinks

I read on google aluminium-canned fruit should last for months without getting spoiled

Am I missing any steps of doing this properly?

Comment: Does the aluminum have a food grade coating? Have you sterilised the food? I make jam and I have jars that are still good after 10 years.

Comment: 10 years? Extraordinary. Was that glass jar? Yes i believe it's food grade since the factory i took the can from, produced them for 500ml beer. No i haven't done anything to "sterilize". I guess i should try heating on 70 Celcius now to pasteurize the juice?

Comment: Normal canning procedures heat to 100 C.

Comment: Some soft drink cans have a plastic liner bonded to the aluminum. Would this aspect have bearing on the result? Perhaps aluminum reacts with food? I suspect it does in some manner.

Comment: @ookla read the directions for `home canning` ... you have to pasteurize the food

Comment: Just sealing food also seals in the microorganisms with the food. Did you not realize that canned food is sealed then HEATED to kill everything that is inside? This is regular procedure when making jams at home except that they use jars. They seal the jars then submerge them in boiling water.

Comment: @DKNguyen I sterlise the jars and lids, which mens the glass is preheated, then fill with boiling jam and close rapidly. They even get their own "vacuum" seal as the contents shrink on cooling. Never used a boiling bath after and nor has my mum who has been making jam for the best part of 75 years...

Comment: @SolarMike I guess that's similar enough. Either way, the contents are at a high enough temperature to kill everything in it after it has been sealed.

Comment: @DKNguyen and it is also the sugar content. I do a mean whisky marmalade :)

Comment: You don't need an engineering stack exchange, you need a book on canning.  Try the Mormons, they're big on this.  Doing this by trial and error is a good way to kill yourself or somebody else.

Comment: @TigerGuy More relevant on Food/Cooking SE also.

Comment: As for a book, the best one I have is: Good Housekeeping Complete book of Home Preserving, published 1981, long out of print so secondhand bookshops... :)

Comment: thank you everyone for the suggestion @SolarMike i just tried putting boiled juice into the can and sealed it. after like 30 minutes, the can dented (like this https://www.wideopeneats.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Untitled-design3.png). so after boiling, i guess should do cooling as well before putting them in cans?

Comment: @DKNguyen i will try your suggestion after this, dipping them in boiled water after being filled with content

Comment: all "home canning" videos using mason jar, which is very thick, heat-resistant and won't dented, unfortunately. but i got the idea of sterilize it first